# How do I build and install python3-dev and python3-sip-dev on win10?

Tags: python, makefile, cmake, pyqt5

(windows 10, visual studio is installed, and I'm using visual studio's install location for python. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared))

I've been trying to build ultimaker cura's libarcus library. Luckily, vcpkg had all the dependencies Cmake needed except for python3-dev and python3-sip-dev. If you'd like to take a look at the directions/repo, it is here: https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus

at first I thought pip3 install sip would work fine, but it only installed a single python file (sip.pyd) and the distribution notes (sip-4.19.8.dist-info file). I need source code, or at least the entire release folder, I think. Could anyone with sip installed on debian, ubuntu, or linux confirm that there is more on those platforms?

here's the cmake output in case it might help, or I'm missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
  implicitly converting '' to 'STRING' type.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:266 (_find_package):
  By not providing "FindSIP.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SIP", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SIP" with any of
  the following names:

    SIPConfig.cmake
    sip-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SIP" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "SIP_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SIP" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```See also "C:/cura-git/deps/libarcus-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
````

Comment: I don't thinkg the c++ tag belongs here...

Comment: you're right-removed. I forgot arcus wasn't a well known repo- it, along with sip, are for going between c++ and python.

Comment: python-dev and python-sip-dev are names of the python and sip packages of ubuntu, in windows the first package comes with python, and the second is the package https://pypi.org/project/SIP/

Comment: yes, but as it says in my post, that didn't provide the correct files. I have almost been able to install it, though I'm getting a more  singular error now (access denied). I'm closing this topic as such.